# It is possible to avoid creation of proguard/dump.txt output file?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I have a problem with dump.txt file output from proguard. I want that proguard dont generate that file.

I'm using proguard in a huge android project, with this configuration:

- ignorewarnings
- dontobfuscate

I use dontobfuscate because i want to see exception details in logcat.

I use ignorewarnings because i have a lot of warnings because this huge android project has this project structure:

- Project 1: Launcher (it is referencing two library projects:
  MyLibrary project and Google PLay Services)
- Project 2: Google Play Services
- Project 3: MyLibrary

MyLibrary Project has a lot of jars and frameworks being referenced. So i get a lot of proguard warnings on Launcher project, and because of this i added -ignorewarnings to proguard configuration file.

Why i have a 100MBytes dumb.txt file inside my Launcher project proguard folder? How can i avoid this file generation?

Thanks

Comment: By "i want to see exception details", you mean that you want to make APK so that you can read the logs?

Comment: not exactly, but it does matter for this problem?

Comment: Yes it is better to know what EXACTLY you want to do by doing this hack. Can you give a few reasons? You can totally skip ProGuard as well, but that's not recommended.